# Plotting Pivot Tables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
airline     review
United      neutral
United      neutral
United      negative
Southwest   negative
Delta       positive
Delta       positive
```

I then converted it into a pivot table:

```
a = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['airline', 'review'], aggfunc = len)
a
airline    review
United     neutral     2
United     negative    1
Southwest  negative    1
Delta      positive    2
```

Then plotted:

```
a.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8uY2.png)

How can I get each airlines reviews to plot together as different colors for each type of review, all sorted together (much like a pivot chart would in Excel)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to unstack the `reviews` index as columns:

```
a.unstack('review').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]